# Mitigating shared library bottlenecks while running many processes

Tags: performance, numpy, shared-libraries, intel-mkl, numa

I'm doing some benchmarking on a 2 socket motherboard with 2 Intel 6230's (total of 40 cores).  The computer is running RHEL-7.6 and utilizes NUMA.  My ultimate goal is to determine the performance difference between using Intel's MKL library on an Intel vs. an AMD machine.

I installed `python-3.7.3` using Anaconda.  Looking at `numpy`'s shared library:

```
ldd /home/user/local/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00002aaaaaacc000)
    libmkl_rt.so => /home/user/local/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/../../../../libmkl_rt.so (0x00002aaaaaccf000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002aaaab3b6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aaaab5d2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002aaaab995000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002aaaaaaab000)
```

You can see that it depends on `libmkl_rt.so`.  Presumably the linear algebra routines like `np.dot()` depend on this.  So I run the following code, `numpy_test.py` :

```
import numpy as np
matrixSize = 5000     # outer dim of mats to run on
N = 50       # num of trials 
np.random.seed(42)
Ax = matrixSize
Ay = 10000
Bx = 10000
By = matrixSize
A=np.random.rand(Ax,Ay)
B=np.random.rand(Bx,By)
npStartTime = time.time()
for i in range(N):
    AB = np.dot(A,B)
print("Run time : {:.4f} s".format((time.time() - npStartTime)))
```

Running this with <strike>one core</strike>(wrong, see below) takes about 17.5 seconds.  If I run it on all 40 cores simultaneously, the average run time is 1200s for each process. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839945/4021436) attempts to provide a solution for mitigating this problem.  Two of the possible solutions don't even work and the third option (`dplace`) doesn't seem to be easily accessible for RHEL 7.6.

**Question**

1. Is it plausible that the huge performance hit when running 40 processes is due to all the  processes competing for access to the shared library (presumably `libmkl_rt.so`) which only lives in one place in memory?
2. If true, are there modern solutions to force each core to use its own copy of a shared library?  I can't seem to find a static version of `libmkl_rt.so` to build `numpy` on.

**EDIT**

Following the suggestion of Gennady.F.Intel, I ran :

```
$ export MKL_VERBOSE=1; python3 src/numpy_attempt.py
Numpy + Intel(R) MKL: THREADING LAYER: (null)
Numpy + Intel(R) MKL: setting Intel(R) MKL to use INTEL OpenMP runtime
Numpy + Intel(R) MKL: preloading libiomp5.so runtime
MKL_VERBOSE Intel(R) MKL 2019.0 Update 4 Product build 20190411 for Intel(R) 64 architecture Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions 512 (Intel(R) AVX-512) with support of Vector Neural Network Instructions enabled processors, Lnx 2.10GHz lp64 intel_thread
MKL_VERBOSE SDOT(2,0x555555c71cc0,1,0x555555c71cc0,1) 2.58ms CNR:OFF Dyn:1 FastMM:1 TID:0  NThr:40
MKL_VERBOSE DGEMM(N,N,5000,5000,10000,0x7fffffffc870,0x2aaad834b040,5000,0x2aaac05d2040,10000,0x7fffffffc878,0x2aaaf00c4040,5000) 370.98ms CNR:OFF Dyn:1 FastMM:1 TID:0  NThr:40
.
.
```

So I think the contention for resources has more to do with the fact that each of my 40 instances is asking for 40 threads each for a total of 1600 threads. If I `export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1` and run my 40 instances of `numpy_test.py` the average run time is ~440 seconds. Running a single instance of `numpy_test.py` on the machine takes 240s. I think the discrepancy is explained, but the questions are yet to be answered.

Comment: Could you try to see what mkl will return by setting "export MKL_VERBOSE=1" environment variable?

Comment: Great suggestion.  See above edits.  It solves the massive run time difference, but doesn't illuminate the answers to the questions.

Comment: yes, this is the typical threads oversubscription problems and MKL has only one solution to run the code with 1 thread only, but you already found out this solution by himself.